# Custom Error Pages with Layout

Tags: c#, html, .net, dynamic, error-handling

I've been fighting to get custom error pages to work and keep finding my way back to simply using a static page. Though the static page works, it would require remaking the navigation bar which we would like to avoid at this time. I'm currently using the following to specify custom error pages.

Asp.net Error Handling

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

IIS Error Handling

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/404.html" responseMode="File"/>
</httpErrors>
```

Is there a method of implementing dynamic custom error pages that can handle for both IIS errors and Asp.net errors?

Comment: Take a look at my suggestion and see if it can be applied in your scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around the same issue in my ASP.Net MVC projects by piping everything through .Net via handlers.

```xml
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*.*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

First an `ErrorController` was created to handle request errors and not found requests like.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class ErrorController : Controller {
    // GET: Error
    public ActionResult NotFound() {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Error() {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        return View();
    }
}
```

You will notice that I call `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` to try to avoid IIS errors

Then a base controller to handle all unknown actions that would map to the `ErrorController.NotFound` action was created.

```
public abstract class FrontOfficeControllerBase : Controller {
    protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName) {
        var data = ViewData;
        //Custom code to resolve the view.
        //ViewResult view = this.View<ErrorController>(c => c.NotFound());

        //Manually create view with view Data
        ViewResult view = new ViewResult();
        view.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
        view.ViewData["controller"] = "Error";
        view.ViewData["action"] = "NotFound";

        if (data != null && data.Count > 0) {
            data.ToList().ForEach(view.ViewData.Add);
        }

        Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        view.ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
    }
}
```

All `Controllers` would inherit from this base controller.

A catch all route was configured after all other routes.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "404-NotFound",
    url: "NotFound",
    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "500-Error",
    url: "Error",
    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Error" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CatchAll",
    url: "{*any}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" });
```

This made sure that if a route was not matched to any of my controllers it would safely route to the `ErrorController.NotFound` action.

For the views, I created the respective `NotFound.shtml` and `Error.cshtml` paged in the  `Views/Shared` folder and they benefited from access to the root layout, which is what I think you were looking for.

In the end I was able to remove both the `customErrors` and `httpErrors` from `web.config` as there was no longer any need for them as every request was managed by the handlers and routed accordingly.

The original idea for this structure came from this article where I mixed and matched the available options till I found a solution that worked/suited my needs.

[Exception handling in ASP.NET MVC (6 methods explained)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/850062/Exception-handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC-methods-explaine#ExceptionhandlinginASP.NETMVC(6methodsexplained))

Hope this helps.

Comment: Going to give this a go and report back. Thanks!

Comment: So the only two ways I was able to get this to work was to use ViewResult view = new ErrorsController(this.ControllerContext).NotFound(); which for some reason results in it ignoring the override method which I'm not really sure I understand as the other way resulted in a null context for the controller but it found the HandleUnknownAction. The code itself seems to hinge on this.View<ErrorController> however I can't find anyway to perform this operation as View can't accept a type argument.

Comment: With a bit of tweaking due to certain items, I found this worked and would definitely recommend it for others!

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this as well and searched for a long time.  As far as I can tell there is no way to create a dynamic custom error page that gets served up for IIS Errors for requests that don't enter the .net pipeline.  Like you, I ended up having two 404 error pages.  One dynamic .aspx one for file not founds errors resulting from requests that entered the .net pipeline, and one .html one for file not found requests that never entered the .net pipeline.  The person who downvoted your question probably didn't realize that you are asking a very good, and difficult question, that has no easy solution.  I will upvote your question to help compensate.

Comment: I'd spent time looking but only ever found answers pointing to static pages as the way to go. It made me worry that I might not be asking the right question, so thank you for easing my concerns. I'll stick with the static pages and do what I can from there!

Comment: @RonC, take a look at my suggestion and see if it can be applied in this scenario.

Comment: @Nkoshi - Without doing a deep dive into you code I agree that one potential work around is to route *all* requests into the dot net pipeline.  In such a case all 404's can be handled by a dynamic .aspx page.  It doesn't solve the root problem of how to serve a dynamic aspx page for IIS errors that don't route into the pipeline though.  Also, routine *all* requests (images, etc) through the .net pipeline places a large performance burden on the server that many developers may not want to bear (myself included). As an aside, I do route .html requests through the pipeline to handle their errors.

Comment: @RonC I understand what you mean.

Comment: I've marked Nkosi's answer as correct though I want people to note that this is also a correct answer as Nkosi's depends on circumstances and the goal in mind!

Comment: @J-Americano  No worries. I'm surprised that you'd be willing to run all your image requests through the .net pipeline due to the performance implications of substantially increasing the requests per second that .Net will need to handle.  But if your site is a low traffic site (or you have very few images per page) perhaps it's not a big deal in your situation.

Comment: Sadly I'm still new to stackoverflow in terms of posting and marking things correct. His answer is what lead me to my final solution and though his answer did "work" it was too much of a performance hit for our site. I tweaked his solution to avoid using the <handler> code and instead setup an Application_Error method in Global.asax.cs which catches the errors before IIS can do anything with them. The result is having dynamic error pages that make use of layouts as I had hoped, while avoiding the performance hit. Should I edit my question to show the final result?

Comment: That's very cool but I'm surprised you could catch a 404 error for an image request via Application_Error if you are not running all the image requests through the .net pipeline.  It'd be cool to post that solution as it's own answer even if you leave the "accepted" answer the way it is to reward him for his help.

Comment: @J-Americano, I am interested in your eventual solution. Sounds interesting. Like RonC said you should also post you solution as an answer. Could prove helpful to others, myself included.