# Custom Error Handler

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5

I have searched the web and stitched together an error handling solution that doesn't work mainly because I don't understand fully how the exception pipeline works. I used different guides, but I didn't get any of theme to work for me. What I want the error handler to do is this. I have a class called workplanRepo where all my queries are executed. I have covered all queries with a try and catch block. What I want is when an error occurs is for an exception to be thrown that allows me to customize a specific message for each query and the default exception message. I then want to be able to retrieve the messages in the error view that the exception handler has redirected the user to. I would also like a default handler that catches all other errors. but don't necessarily have the custom message part. If anybody could explain or show me how I can achieve this. I would be very grateful!. This is one of the query methods:

```
try {
    newItem["Author"] = _user.Id;
    newItem["Title"] = _user.Title; 

    newItem.Update();
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
      throw new HttpException("Oops, there must have been an error: " + e.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this article https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/850062/Exception-handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC-methods-explaine#ExceptionhandlinginASP.NETMVC(6methodsexplained)

Comment: Which also influenced my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247900/custom-error-pages-with-layout/38249656#38249656

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC 5, we can catch error inside Global.asax.cs's ***Application_Error event*** instead of using try catch block in every query. From then redirect to custom error page.

In addition, we can also use logging framework like ***Log4Net*** and ***NLog***.

*For example,*

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();

        LogException(exception);

        if (exception is HttpAntiForgeryException)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

            // Call target Controller and pass the routeData.
            IController controller = EngineContext.Current.Locator.GetInstance<CommonController>();

            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Common");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "AntiForgery");

            var requestContext = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
            controller.Execute(requestContext);
        }
        else
        {
            // Process 404 HTTP errors
            var httpException = exception as HttpException;
            if (httpException != null && httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Server.ClearError();
                Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

                // Call target Controller and pass the routeData.
                IController controller = EngineContext.Current.Locator.GetInstance<CommonController>();

                var routeData = new RouteData();
                routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Common");
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "PageNotFound");

                var requestContext = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
                controller.Execute(requestContext);
            }
        }
    }

    private void LogException(Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex == null)
            return;

        // Ignore 404 HTTP errors
        var httpException = ex as HttpException;
        if (httpException != null &&
            httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404)
            return;

        try
        {
            // Log error message
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Don't throw new exception if occurs
        }
    }
```

*You can view sample project which use Log4Net at [GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Global.asax.cs#L44).*

Comment: Thank you very much!!! it worked. Do you know how to check a viewbag for content and if not null show a modal. I know how to use the viewbag in a razorview but I never seem to be able to fuse razorview/C# with javascript

Comment: Could you create a new question and elaborate a little bit more? It will be helpful if you provide a sample code on where you get stuck.

Comment: I tried to create a question, but there is a 90min timer until I can create a new question. I`ll do it tomorrow